# Ist die Frage zum Usus einer bestimmten Schriftart On-Topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Diese Frage

[Why was Fraktur abolished in Germany?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43523/why-was-fraktur-abolished-in-germany)

scheint mir nicht wirklich nach einem sprachspezifischen Problem zu fragen, sondern lediglich zum Gebrauch einer bestimmten Schriftart.

Warum die "Nazis" diese Schriftart verbannt haben, hat nichts mit dem deutschen Sprachgebrauch an sich zu tun, und die Gründe sind wohl eher in der (bereits erfolgten) historischen Nachforschung zu suchen, oder provozieren Antworten, die lediglich auf Annahmen oder Meinungen basieren.

Meiner Meinung nach ist diese Frage hier nicht schlüssig und definitiv beantwortbar hier.

Comment: Ist Fraktur nicht eine ganze Klasse von Schriftarten? Als Schritart würde ich etwas wie Andale Mono bezeichnen, aber schon "serifenlose Schrift" als Schriftartentyp oder -klasse. Der Unterschied zwischen einer Serifenschrift u. einer serifenlosen ist aber kleiner, als der von von einer solchen zu einer Frakturschrift.

Answer (score 5):

Wenn es darum geht, welche Fragen auf diese Seite passen, sollte es m. E. primär darum gehen, ob wir Fragen gut beantworten können, und Antworten dazu beurteilen können, und weniger ob sie in gewisse Schubladen passen.
Da die Geschichte der Fraktur in Deutschland eng mit der deutschen Sprache verwoben ist, werden sich kaum Experten hierfür finden, die nicht auch Experten zur deutschen Sprache sind.
Deshalb würde ich die meisten solcher Fragen schon für geeignet für diese Seite halten. Insofern würde ich die Titelfrage mit *ja* beantworten.

Andererseits ist der Titel der Frage, der Stein des Anstoßes war, (»Why was Fraktur abolished in Germany?«) etwas vielschichtiger.
Man könnte sie z. B. wie folgt aufteilen:

1. Welche Ereignisse und Mechanismen haben dazu geführt, dass die Fraktur im deutschen Sprachraum außer Gebrauch geriet?
2. Was war die Motivation hinter dem Verbot der Frakturschrift der Nazis?

Die erste Frage würde ich prinzipiell als klar für diese Seite geeignet betrachten, auch wenn es wahrscheinlich schwierig ist, hierauf eine belastbare Antwort zu geben.

Bei der zweiten Frage geht es weniger um den Gebrauch der Fraktur, sondern um vielschichtiges politisches Kalkül, was nicht unsere Stärke ist und besser auf [History SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/) aufgehoben wäre.
So wie ich die Frage verstehe, geht es eigentlich nur um Teil Nr. 2.

Comment: Absatz 1 verwundert mich etwas. Das klingt so, als ob sich eine Frage dadurch qualifiziert, dass sie von den Stammusern beantwortet werden kann. Das darf m.E. kein Kriterium sein. Überhaupt kann sich im ungünstigen Fall erst nach Jahren jemand finden, der eine Antwort geben kann.

Comment: *Das klingt so, als ob sich eine Frage dadurch qualifiziert, dass sie von den Stammusern beantwortet werden kann* – Mehr oder weniger: ja. Etwas genauer gesagt: Die Frage kann von uns besser beantwortet werden als von durchschnittlichen (deutschsprachigen) Internetnutzern. Auch wenn es oberflächlich so scheinen mag (und natürlich stark korreliert ist), sind SE-Seiten nach Communities getrennt, nicht nach Themen. Anders gesehen: Warum schließen wir denn Fragen, die nichts mit unserem Thema zu tun haben? Weil wir sie nicht beantworten können bzw. Antworten nicht beurteilen können.

Comment: Das ist ja eine zirkuläre Bestimmung dessen, was ein Thema für die Site ist. Die überwiegende Mehrheit hier scheint mir im IT-Bereich zu arbeiten, aber inhaltlich würden Deutschlehrer viel eher passen - die kennen nur die Seite nicht. Ich stimme sehr oft für das Schließen von Fragen, die ich beantworten kann ("Entziffert mir diesen Grabstein", "Was genau bedeutet "Schrank"") und sehr oft nicht, die ich nicht beantworten kann (Modalverben bei präpostionaler Bestimmung im Konjunktiv II).

Comment: @userunknown: *Das ist ja eine zirkuläre Bestimmung dessen, was ein Thema für die Site ist.* – Nicht ganz. Die Community ist wiederum klar umschrieben: »speakers of all levels who want to share and increase their knowledge of the German language«. Eine feindliche Übernahme durch Programmierer ist also ausgeschlossen.

Comment: @userunknown: *Ich stimme sehr oft für das Schließen von Fragen, die ich beantworten kann* – Wir schließen nur selten Fragen, weil sie nicht zum Thema der Seite passen. Die meisten Fragen schließen wir wegen anderen Problemen, z. B., dass wir nicht wollen, dass diese Seite eine Wörterbuch-ähnliche Datenbank wird. (Dass unsere seitenspezifischen Schließgründe unter »off-topic« eingeordnet sind, ist technischen Beschränkungen geschuldet.)

Comment: Also wieso die Nazis die Frakturschrift abschafften gehört für mich klar zum Wissen über die dt. Sprache.

Answer (score 1):

> Warum die "Nazis" diese Schriftart verbannt haben, hat nichts mit dem
>   deutschen Sprachgebrauch an sich zu tun,

Schriftsprache ist eine Unterklasse von Sprachgebrauch.

> und die Gründe sind wohl eher in der (bereits erfolgten) historischen
>   Nachforschung zu suchen,

Sie sind vielleicht mittels historischer Nachforschung zu suchen, sicher nicht in dieser. Das funktioniert ja schon zeitlich nicht.

> oder provozieren Antworten, die lediglich auf Annahmen oder Meinungen
>   basieren.

Antworten, die nur Meinungen wiedergeben kann man abwerten und mit Kommentaren kritisieren. Das ist kein schlüssiger Grund eine Frage zu schließen.

> Was war die Motivation hinter dem Verbot der Frakturschrift der Nazis?

Solange diese Frage nicht beantwortet ist, halte ich es für verfrüht, festzustellen, dass es zu wenig mit der deutschen Sprache zu tun hat.

Comment: Gibt es eigentlich die Möglichkeit, eine Frage mitsamt Antworten auf ein anderes SE zu migrieren? Wenn ja, dann könnte man sich darauf einigen solche Fragen eine Zeit lang offen zu lassen, um a posteriori entscheiden zu können, ob es hier her passt.

Comment: Da bin ich der falsche Adressat. Weder kenne ich mich so gut mit dem SE-Netzwerk aus, noch bin ich überhaupt dafür die Frage zu migrieren. Sie hat ja offensichtlich nichts mit romanischen Sprachen zu tun, sondern ganz speziell mit der deutschen Sprache. Aber je nach dem wie es den Leuten passt gehen sie wohl mal davon aus, dass es nur um gesprochene Sprache geht, dann wieder, dass es  nur um Schriftsprache geht.